# Floating button not showing inside a tabbed activity

Tags: android, android-studio, floating-action-button

I am trying to create a floating action button inside a tabbed activity. I am facing the below issues,

1.The floating button is not showing at the bottom right of the page even after adding gravity and allign parent right.

2.The android floating button is not reflecting when testing it on emulator.

I think there is an issue with my project as I tested it on a blank activity and it was working perfectly fine but it is not working with my activity.

Activity used- Navigation drawer activity.

XML code

```
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
        fab:menu_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
        fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
        fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
        fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
        fab:menu_colorNormal="#DA4336"
        fab:menu_colorPressed="#E75043"
        fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
        fab:menu_icon="@drawable/ic_category"
        fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
        fab:menu_labels_showAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_in_from_right"
        fab:menu_labels_hideAnimation="@anim/fab_slide_out_to_right"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
        fab:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
        fab:menu_labels_textColor="#FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
        fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
        fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="#333333"
        fab:menu_labels_colorPressed="#444444"
        fab:menu_labels_colorRipple="#66FFFFFF"
        fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
        fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
        fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
        fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
        fab:menu_labels_position="left"
        fab:menu_openDirection="up"
        fab:menu_backgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        fab:menu_fab_label="your_label_here"
        fab:menu_fab_show_animation="@anim/show_from_bottom"
        fab:menu_fab_hide_animation="@anim/hide_to_bottom">

        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/menu_item"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_entertainment"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_label="Entertainment" />

    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:titleTextColor="#3F51B5"
        android:background="@drawable/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp" />
```

;

```
<include layout="@layout/content_main"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

I have attached both the screenshot of without adding the FAB code and after adding the FAB Code in XML file.

- Before

[image]

- After

[image]

Comment: can you put your full XML ?

Comment: I tried but it is the site is showing some error.. As it is a navigation activity, there are several XML layouts linked to Main activity.

Comment: Move it out of the `AppBarLayout`, and put it directly in the `CoordinatorLayout`, after the main content.

Comment: The position of the floating button is changed however the button is still not visible..

Answer (score 0):

refer this xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/maincontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad_view">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <SearchView
                        android:id="@+id/search"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:clickable="true">

                    </SearchView>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp" />


        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#fff">

            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="42dp"
                android:src="@drawable/fab"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

                android:id="@+id/viewpager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</RelativeLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation"
    android:name="com.panchu.voixme.fragment.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Appbarlayout

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
  android:id="@+id/appbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

for more you can refer [floating-action-button](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/12/android-material-design-floating-action-button/)

Comment: I have separate XML layouts in the template.. Can you suggest the codes only for app_bar_layout